# Can Rails' test environment tell MySQL to be memory-only?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I'm running my Rails rspec tests, there is a lot of interaction with the database. This is slow.

I know that the best advice to speed up testing is "reduce your database interactions". But I also wondered if I can make MySQL behave differently. The test data typically only needs to exist for a fraction of a second at a time, so there should never be much of it.

Can I tell MySQL not to write to the hard disk? Can I limit this behavior to my Rails development environment (maybe I need a separate install of MySQL server)?

Comment: I know that SQLite has a memory-only mode, and I could use that as my test database, but I'm afraid I may have some MySQL-specific code and want to test it realistically.

Comment: You could create a MySQL instance that runs off of RAM disk, possibly.

Comment: Convert all your MySQL tables to type "MEMORY (HEAP)" - these are held in memory(RAM) rather than on disk: see here [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

Comment: How'd your experiment go?

Comment: @digger69 - never got back around to it. The MEMORY storage engine wasn't doable for me because it doesn't support foreign keys. Lately I've been playing with PostgreSQL and you always tell its server, at startup, where to look for data files. Seems like using a RAM disk would be easy there. Also definitely no need for a separate install with PostgreSQL; just a different process running from the same executable.

Comment: You might want to look into optimizing MySQL on your Dev/CI to run tests. For example: 1. If you use innodb_file_per_table=1 then TRUNCATE statements are horribly slow. Do not use it or you can tell rspec database cleaner to use delete instead of truncate. 2. Again, if you use InnoDB - relax acid safety by setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

Answer (score 0):

mysql is fast enough.

What you really want to do is set up fixtures and transactional tests.  That way every test starts with the test data you need and you just rollback the transaction between tests.

Makes a HUGE difference.